# Building a 'bot' that lives in a Google Spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps, google-sheets, google-apps-script, google-sheets-api

I'm wondering if there's Google Apps API support for building a bot that lives in a Spreadsheet and interacts with users via the in-document chat features.  I can't find a Google Apps API that defines calls to view and send messages for in-document chat, but I figured I'd ask in here case I'm missing anything!

If this doesn't exist, any suggestions about how I might build out this type of functionality?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am fairly certain there is no official API for the in-document chat. I do know that the regular [Google chat](http://code.google.com/apis/talk/) uses [XMPP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extensible_Messaging_and_Presence_Protocol); the in-document chat probably just uses a more limited version.

In theory, I suppose Google should not be able to differentiate between a program and a user. You might be able to reverse-engineer the chat protocol by digging through the source or inspecting the network. You could also run a browser on your machine and simulate mouse and keyboard input, like a regular input.

Alternatively, you could interact with the user using the spreadsheet itself, via the [Google Spreadsheet API](http://code.google.com/apis/spreadsheets/).